# Android Keyboard layout based on user preference

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an Android Keyboard using Softkey keyboard example in native language.

Now, I want user to be able to set keyborder,have a option of setting background colors,size and similar customization available and correspondingly appropriate keyboard should be generated.

Can anyone please guide me the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **color setting**

You need define your custom color scheme in your code. I store it in XML file.

```
<theme>
    <!--define color-->
    <color-def name="key_white" value="#F9F9FA"/>
    <!--<color-def name="light_gray" value="#D4D6D7"/>-->
    <color-def name="white" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <color-def name="shadow_black" value="#828386"/>
    <color-def name="text_black" value="#000000"/>
    <color-def name="light_gray" value="#BAC2C7"/>
    <color-def name="cute_blue" value="#194FDC"/>
    ...
```

Then, parse this xml file, and apply these color values to `onDraw()` method.

- **size setting**

Do it in the similar way, when drawing keyboard, using parameters which defined by user to determine size information.

I have made contribution to an input method software. The key of developing custom keyboard is designing the structure properly.